Command Pattern implementation for movement in Unity
I am developing a game in Unity and attempting to clean up some code and increase re-usability. I have a basic player movement script that looks like this:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations;
using UnityEngine.TextCore.Text;


//TODO - refactor this as a design pattern -- in progress
// Implementing command pattern for userInput
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField] private readonly float speed = 5;
    private bool grounded;
    private void Awake()
    {
        // Grab references for rigidbody and animator from object
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.SetBool("grounded", true);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");


        CharacterFacing(horizontalInput);
        

        CharacterRun(horizontalInput);

        Jump();
        // TODO - add jumpBuffer implementation. Should use Time.Delta value.
        
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        anim.SetFloat("jumpAsc", body.velocity.y);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, speed);
            body.inertia = 30;
            grounded = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && body.velocity.y > 0)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, 0);
            body.AddForce(5.0f * body.mass * Physics.gravity);
        }
    }

    private void CharacterFacing(float horizontalInput)
    {
                // flip character left/right
        if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        else if (horizontalInput < -0.01f)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    }
    private void CharacterRun(float horizontalInput)
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);
        anim.SetFloat("run", Math.Abs(body.velocity.x));
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D()
    {
        grounded = true;
        body.inertia = 10;
        anim.SetBool("grounded", grounded);
    }
}

And I am attempting to refactor it into a Command Pattern. I have moved all of the logic into a class called Character that will be used as a parent to Player and Enemies subclasses. Here it is, largely unchanged:
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _body;
    private Animator _anim;
    private int _HP;
    private float _speed = 5;
    private float _jumpForce;
    private int _level;
    private bool _grounded;

    public Character()
    {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _anim.SetBool("grounded", true);
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        _anim.SetFloat("jumpAsc", _body.velocity.y);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && _grounded)
        {
            _body.velocity = new Vector2(_body.velocity.x, _speed);
            _body.inertia = 30;
            _grounded = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && _body.velocity.y > 0)
        {
            _body.velocity = new Vector2(_body.velocity.x, 0);
            _body.AddForce(5.0f * _body.mass * Physics.gravity);
        }
    }

    private void CharacterFacing(float horizontalInput)
    {
                // flip character left/right
        if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        else if (horizontalInput < -0.01f)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        _body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * _speed, _body.velocity.y);
        _anim.SetFloat("run", Math.Abs(_body.velocity.x));
    }
}

So now my Player subclass is cleaned up:
class Player : Character
{
    Character _player;
    UserInput _userInput;

    public Player(UserInput userInput)
    {
        _player = gameObject.AddComponent<Character>();
        _userInput = gameObject.AddComponent<UserInput>();
    }

}

and user input is split off:
using UnityEngine;

public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Character _character;

    public UserInput(Character character)
    {
        _character = character;
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            ICommand storedCommand = new JumpCommand(_character);
            storedCommand.Execute();
        }
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            ICommand storedCommand = new RunCommand(_character);
            storedCommand.Execute();
        }
    }
}

But now my player character does not move. All the character does is fall to the ground (which tells me my Rigidbody2D is initializing correctly at least). I am not sure how to tie this all together to listen for user inputs.
I tried creating a UserInput object in the Player class, hoping it would use the Update() function there to catch user input. I also tried creating an event system in Unity and attaching my UserInput script to that. It feels like I'm so close, but I'm not sure how to tie it all together.

You could try looking into MediatR nuget package.

Sounds like time to debug. See whats called. Whats not.

MonoBehaviours should not have constructors. You need to replace them with Awake and Start methods. Also, there is something strange happening with component addition, as right now you are trying to add Character from Player which is itself a subclass of Character.

EventSystem is only used for UI. Also when you AddComponent, that doesn't use the Constructor. I don't see anywhere in your  code setting UserInput.character. If you have some kind of silent failure in your Run/JumpCommand where you pass them null objects and they do nothing, you won't get any error.

I will give this a shot when I’m back home.

Use Awake instead of the constructors! it doesn't move because this line is never called in the first place _userInput = gameObject.AddComponent<UserInput>(); so the component does never exist at all ... Something you should've easily found out by inspecting your objects on runtime ....

@derHugo, sadly a lot of people, including newcomers, do not use debuggers....Also +1 on the Awake vs Constructor. I forgot to explicitly mention that.

@Vladimir @derHugo @NPatch
Yes! It was the issue of using a constructor vs Awake() as well as setting up my UserInput script properly in the hierarchy.
Now the Character class looks like:
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _body;
    private Animator _anim;
    private int _HP;
    private float _speed = 5;
    private float _jumpForce;
    private int _level;
    private bool _grounded;

    public void Awake()
    {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _anim.SetBool("grounded", true);
    }
    public void Jump()
    {
        //Jump logic
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        //Run logic
    }

And the player class is a subclass with some special variables for player weapons and abilities, etc...
public class Player : Character
{
    private int weapon;
    private int type;
    // etc...
}

Once I added the Awake() function to my Character class, the script automatically appeared in my UserInput script inspector. This also took care of the error about the reference pointing to null object.
It was important to me to get this into a command pattern. I am trying to implement a bunch of new things I'm learning at once, which is sometimes difficult. But I'm glad I did it!
Feels good! Thanks for the help, nudging me in the right direction.

I guess this line would still not be right _player = gameObject.AddComponent<Character>(); ... your Player already IS a Character .. you should probably also mark your Character class as abstract in order to avoid direct instantiation of it
